# Use raspberry pi pics to record rpm on a wheel

Tags: electronics, pi-pico, robotics

I would like to use a raspberry pi pick to record the rpm of a wheel on a rc car. There will be a contact on the wheel, and a contact on the body of the car. As the wheel turns, if the two contacts touch, the pico should record a single revolution. It should do this by recording a 1 if the contacts touch, and a 0 when they don’t. I am flexible with how the data is recorded though, it does not have to be a 1 and 0 if it cannot be. In a minute there may be over 8000 rpm’s. The pico must record data continuously. I was wondering if this was possible with a pico? I can build the contacts very easily, but which raspberry pi libraries should I use? Also which gpio pins can I use and how is there a way to make sure the pico isn’t killed by the electricity from the contacts?

Comment: Any microprocessor could handle this task.  Perhaps look at the Pico documentation?

Comment: why should the contacts generate any electricity?

Comment: `In a minute there may be over 8000 rpm’s` ... that's 8000 RPMPM ... makes no sense

Comment: This might help: https://forum.pi-top.com/t/making-a-rpi-pico-based-smart-vehicle/924/14#